# Mute whatsapp specific group calls/ring tone

Tags: audio

I am aware there is an option to mute entirely the whatsapp calls. However, I want to keep the ring tone for individual but not for groups.

I can mute the notifications and the groups. But even with that, even my phone has 'don't disturb mode' is enabled, the group rings aren't muted (when someone in the group makes a group call).

I searched every option in the system & app and couldn't find a way to mute them.

My phone is rooted though.

Answer (score 0):

you can mute all of a group's notifications, that should cover calls, as well.

Mute group notifications:

1. Open the WhatsApp group chat, then tap the group subject.

- Alternatively, tap and hold the group in the CHATS tab.

2. Then, tap the Mute notifications icon in the top corner.
   Tap Mute notifications.
3. Select the length of time you'd like to mute notifications for.

- You can also uncheck Show notifications to stop notifications from being shown in your notifications screen.

4. Tap OK.

Unmute group notifications:

1. Open the WhatsApp group chat, then tap the group subject.

2.Tap Unmute notifications.

- Alternatively, tap and hold the group in the CHATS tab. Then, tap the Unmute notifications icon in the top corner.

ref: https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/how-to-mute-or-unmute-group-notifications/?lang=en

Comment: Thank you. I does mute notifications, however, it does not mute the calls though